# Pass method calls to object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a custom `swipe gesture recognizer` to set allowed angles and distances.
So far it works really well but needs a lot of code in the view controller. So my question is wether it is possible to somehow pass a method call like:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in the view controller to my gesture recogniser object so that I don't have to write something like this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 [self.swipeGestureRecognizer touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

into my view controller. I think the build in `UIGestureRecognizer` does this somehow but I could not figure out how it works.

I really would appreciate your help.

[EDIT]

Generic example: I have an object A which creates an object B. A has a method c that gets called sometimes. What I want to achieve is that a method d of B gets called when c in A gets called. So to somehow forward or pass this method call.

Specific example: The following method gets called in my view controller every time there is a touch on the screen:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

but I actually want my GestureRecognizer object to process this information so I have the same method in my GestureRecognizer object and I want this method to get called every time the counterpart in the view controller gets called.

Comment: can you explain in detail with good example?

Comment: you want to call a method which is in another object without actually calling it? :O

Comment: Hm. Somehow automatically but if you say it that way, it sounds like a stupid thing. ;) But I wonder how the original UIGestureRecognizer does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub class UIGestureRecognizer and create a class called CustomGestureRecognizer.
Its .m file will look like this

```
@implementation CustomGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
   // do your code here
}

@end
```

Some where in the subclass you have to change the state of the recognizer to

> UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized

when the current gesture is registered, else change to

> UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed

.

Now in the view controller where you want to use this recognizer do :

```
CustomGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[CustomGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleChange:)];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Detailed explanation is given here [Apple doc,](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) under subclassing.

Comment: Are you that Jithin Roy?

Comment: I think that's the best way. Thanks.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya yes I am :D

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.swipeGestureRecognizer touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The above will end up with Recursive calls, and your program will crash at some point of time.

Comment: No it will not because I call this in my view controller.